# Using lex to tokenize without failing

Tags: yacc, lex

I'm interested in using `lex` to tokenize my input string, but I do not want it to be possible to "fail". Instead, I want to have some type of `DEFAULT` or `TEXT` token, which would contain all the non-matching characters between recognized tokens.

Anyone have experience with something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the pattern `.` at the end of all your lex rules to match any character that isn't matched by any other rule.  You may also need a `\n` rule to match newlines (a newline is the only character the `.` doesn't match)

If you want to combine adjacent non-matching characters into a single token, that is harder, and is more easily done in the parser.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Chris Dodd's answer, the final rule in any *lex* script should be:

```
. return yytext[0];
```

and don't write any single-character rules like `"+" return PLUS;`. Just use the special characters you recognize directly in the grammar, e.g. `term: term '+' factor;`.

This practice:

- saves you a lot of *lex* rules
- makes your grammar much more readable
- returns illegal characters as tokens to the parser, where you can do anything you like with them, or nothing, in which case you get the benefit of *yacc*'s error recovery.

Comment: using double-quotes in your grammar won't work -- you need to use single quotes.  Of course, you need the double quotes in lex -- single quotes won't work there.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks, it's been quite a while since I did any of this.